# Read CSV and convert string to double

Tags: java, arrays, csv, opencsv

I am new to Java and I am reading a csv file using open CSV and my code is below:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class ParseCSVLineByLine
{
   double arr []=new arr[10];
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      //Build reader instance
      //Read data.csv
      //Default seperator is comma
      //Default quote character is double quote
      //Start reading from line number 2 (line numbers start from zero)
      CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data.csv"), ',' , '"' , 1);

      //Read CSV line by line and use the string array as you want
      String[] nextLine;
      int i=0;
      while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
         if (nextLine != null && i<10) {
            //Verifying the read data here
            arr[i]=Double.parseDouble(Arrays.toString(nextLine).toString());
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
         }
        i++;
       }
   }
}
```

But this does not works.But when I only print

```
Arrays.toString(nextLine).toString()
```

This prints

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
.
.
.
.
[10]
```

I think the conversion is having the problem.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is input in csv file ?

Comment: `Arrays.toString(nextLine)` will most likely result in something that isn't parseable as a double, since even with only one element you'll get the strings you posted, i.e. `"[1]"`. Why not just `Double.parseDouble(nextLine[index])` where `index` is probably 0?

Comment: Thanks for the accept, I am glad my answer was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is:

"[1]"

is not a string that could be parsed as number!

Your problem is that you turn the **array** as a whole into **one** string.

So instead of calling

```
Arrays.toString(nextLine).toString()
```

**iterate** nextLine and give each array member to parseDouble()!

Besides: I am pretty sure you receive a *NumberFormatException* or something alike. The JVM already **tells** you that you are trying to convert an invalid string into a number. You have to learn to **read** those exception messages and **understand** what they mean!

Long story short: your code probably wants to parse "[1]", but you should have it parse "1" instead!